# How to unhide items in psensor?

Tags: gui, sensors, psensor

I installed `psensor` and in the gui I `right clicked` on a sensor and then clicked `hide`. That sensor disappeared from the gui and I don't know how to get it back. Any insight on how to "unhide" a given sensor in psensor would be appreciated.

For clarity this is as opposed to the check box for graph... I have tried restarting my machine as well as re-installing psensor. I have not installed lm-sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1. open PSensor GUI
2. go to *Psensor* → *Sensor Preferences*
3. select needed sensor in the left list
4. switch to *Graph* tab
5. check *Display sensor in the list of sensors* checkbox
6. click *OK*

Comment: The display sensor in list of sensors button of course thank you!